# How to convert NFA to a regular expression?

Tags: regex, nfa

I'm so confused as how to convert a NFA to a regular expression.  I have a NFA where the starting state is also a final state and I'm not sure what I should be doing.  This is what my NFA looks like: [image: NFA]

I have tried to follow guidelines I have found online like here: 
http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/lect_08.pdf

Following the steps on this website, I have broken this NFA into this:

[image]

From here I have broken it down a little further into this (which I think corresponds to step 4)

[image]

At this point I'm not really sure how to proceed.  In class we didn't talk at all about GNFA's so I am especially lost at this point.  Any pointers as to how I should proceed from this point?

Comment: You might try to ask this question at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
First step
```

[image: First]

```
Second step
```

[image]

```
Third step
```

[image]

Than your RegEx : `(ℇ+1+00)(10)*`